# LIVE Database - DMOS - Image Quality Assessment

Tags: image, image-processing, distortion

I am working on a project of Image Quality Assessment in which, I have used [LIVE database of images](http://live.ece.utexas.edu/research/quality/subjective.htm). So far, I have understood that how the images have been distributed with respect to each distortion. When it comes to DMOS, I am unable to understand that how to know that which distorted image belongs to which DMOS value.

In readme.txt file, I have found,

> The file dmos.mat has two arrays of length 982 each: dmos and orgs.
>   orgs(i)==0 for distorted images. The arrays dmos and orgs are arranged
>   by concatenating the dmos (and orgs) variables for each database as
>   follows:
>
> dmos=[dmos_jpeg2000(1:227) dmos_jpeg(1:233) white_noise(1:174)
>   gaussian_blur(1:174) fast_fading(1:174)] where dmos_distortion(i) is
>   the dmos value for image "distortion\imgi.bmp" where distortion can be
>   one of the five described above.

But, I am still confused how can traverse through the DMOS with respect to the images. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 227 images in the subfolder *'**jp2k**'* (***img1.bmp***-***img227.bmp***). The elements ***dmos[1]***-***dmos[227]*** in the *dmos* array, correspond to these images.

There are 233 images in the subfolder ***'jpeg'*** (***img1.bmp***-***img233.bmp***). The elements ***dmos[228]***-***dmos[460]*** in the *dmos* array, correspond to these.

And so on...

[[

- 174 images in the subfolder **'*wn*'** (***img1.bmp***-***img174.bmp***) corresponding to ***dmos[461]***-***dmos[634]*** .
- 174 images in the subfolder **'*gblur*'** (***img1.bmp***-***img174.bmp***) corresponding to ***dmos[635]***-***dmos[808]*** .
- 174 images in the subfolder **'*fastfading*'** (***img1.bmp***-***img174.bmp***) corresponding to ***dmos[809]***-***dmos[982]***.

]]

Answer (score 1):

you can open the dmos.mat file with Matlab, and you can get an array of DMOS, the first 227 of this array are the DMOS of jp2k images. and next 233 are belong to jpeg file, and so on.